# VC++ 2010 Express | Compiler removes some code from my project

Tags: c++

I'm using VC++ 2010 Express.

I have code like that:

```
if(strlen("AA") == strlen("BB"))
 MessageBox("AA == BB");
else
 MessageBox("AA != BB");
```

In the built executable there are bytes "AA == BB", but there is no "AA != BB".

It means the compiler optimizes predictable code.
Is there any way to disable this?

Cheers, Kamil.

Comment: Try turning off optimization.

Comment: To add to what @RossRidge is saying; with optimizations on the compiler sees this line `if(strlen("AA") == strlen("BB"))` and knows that it will never change at runtime, thus the `else` statement is irrelevant to the running code and is compiled out .. with optimizations off, the branching code should still be in the binary, though never reached because of your if statement ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
#pragma function(strlen)
```

to your program at the beginning.

Comment: No, it is the other way round: if intrinsics are enabled, then #pragma function forces a function call for the given function. So this solves the problem: it disables the compile time evaluation of strlen and makes it run time evaluated, the else part stays.

Comment: Oops, you're right .. mis-stated .. but it still doesn't solve the problem, since the `if (strlen("AA") == strlen("BB"))` is always true, thus /Oi is irrelevant to the issue ..

Comment: Yes, it is always true, but the compiler does not know about it, if strlen is called at runtime (which is forced by #pragma function(strlen)).

Comment: it does "know" about it, otherwise the `else` would NOT be compiled out .. inline call or not, the resulting binary output would always be true on that specific if statement .. thus if /Oi is enabled and the call is made to `strlen` as an inline code or a function call (i.e. a `call` in ASM), it wouldn't matter because the line `if (strlen("AA") == strlen("BB"))` always evaluates to true thus the compiler (if something like /O1 or /Ox were enabled), would "compile out" the `else` statement as it can never be  reached by running code .. thus /Oi is irrelevant to the optimization issue

Comment: This is exactly the point of #pragma function(strlen) regardless of any other optimization: The compiler makes no assumptions about strlen, it just calls it as any other function for "AA" and "BB" and does not remove the else part because it makes no assumption about the result of strlen.